# Complex ViewModel - View cannot Automap values from model Advice Needed..

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have a complex `View`.  It has data from 4 `Models`.  The models are all static and work as expected.  I have created a ViewModel to attempt to show just the data needed for this view.  It is made up of Competitors and some complex Classes and Events they participate in.

I have made a complex `ViewModel`.  When I walk through the `Controller`, I can see all three parts being constructed from the `ViewModel`.  Its all there including data.  When I try to map the values using `Intellesense` in the `View`, it has no way of knowing this data, or has no mapping from the complex ViewModel.  Am I doing this right?  I have tried several ways to map these values to the `View`.  I think I need to `initialize` or `map` the values to the `Models` derived from, I just cannot figure out how.
Please advise on how to map these values, data elements to the view.

**ViewModel:**

`Compeditor` is an from an actual model direct to the DB
The rest of the data is gathered from multiple tables and passed to view from controller

```
namespace eManager.Web2.Models
{
    public class CompDetailPlus

    {
        public CompDetailPlus()
    {
        this.Compeditor = new Compeditor();


    }
        public virtual Compeditor Compeditor { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<InEventClass> InEventClass { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<AllEventClasses> AllEventClasses { get; set; }

    }

public class Compeditor
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int CompeditorId { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName  { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string MiddleInt { get; set; }
        public virtual string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
        public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public virtual string CellPhone { get; set; }
        public virtual double Height { get; set; }
        public virtual double Weight { get; set; }
        public virtual int Age { get; set; }
        public virtual int Event_CompId { get; set; }



    }

    public class InEventClass
    {
        public virtual int EventClassID { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
   //duplicate to simplify how the second list is pulled and then combined with first      list
    public class AllEventClasses
    {
        public virtual int EventClassID { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CompeditorDetail(int CompeditorId)
        {
            //Pull the Competitor detail for the ID passed in
            var comp = _db.Compeditors.Single(c => c.CompeditorId == CompeditorId);

            //Pull a list of Event-Classes the competitor is already signed up for on current event
            var nlist = (from o in _db.Compeditors
                         join o2 in _db.Event_Class_Compeditors_s on o.CompeditorId equals CompeditorId
                         where o.CompeditorId.Equals(CompeditorId)
                         join o3 in _db.Event_Classes on o2.EventClassID equals o3.EventClassID
                         where o2.EventClassID.Equals(o3.EventClassID)
                         join o4 in _db.Class_Definitions on o3.ClassID equals o4.Class_Definition_ID
                         where o3.ClassID.Equals(o4.Class_Definition_ID)
                         select new InEventClass()
                         {
                             ClassName = o4.Class_Name,
                             EventClassID = o2.EventClassID,
                             IsSelected = true
                         }).ToList();

            //pull a complete list of Event Classes that are avaiaible
            var totallist = (from o in _db.Event_Classes
                             join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.ClassID equals o2.ClassID
                             where o.ClassID.Equals(o2.ClassID)
                             join o3 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o3.Class_Definition_ID
                             where o2.ClassID.Equals(o3.Class_Definition_ID)
                             join o4 in _db.Events on o.EventID equals o4.EventID
                             where o.EventID.Equals(o4.EventID)
                             where o4.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)
                             select new AllEventClasses()
                             {
                                 ClassName = o3.Class_Name,
                                 EventClassID = o2.EventClassID,
                                 IsSelected = false

                             }).ToList();

            var whatsleft = totallist.Where(eachtotalclass => !(nlist.Any(eachClassIHave => eachClassIHave.EventClassID == eachtotalclass.EventClassID))).ToList();

            var model = new CompDetailPlus { AllEventClasses = whatsleft, Compeditor = comp, InEventClass = nlist };

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**
(Has to show the Competitor detail and a compound list of Event_Classes they are in)
In the view, I cannot see the values for any data.. all error on run and no good for display.

```
@model IEnumerable<eManager.Web2.Models.CompDetailPlus>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Competitor's Detail";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Compeditor</legend>
            <table border="1" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="display-field">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Compeditor.CompeditorId)

                            </div>

                            <b>First Name</b>
                            <div class="display-field">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Compeditor.FirstName)


                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Last Name</b>
                            <div class="display-field">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Compeditor.LastName)

                            </div>
                        </td>


                    @using (Html.BeginForm("CompeditorDetail", "Compeditor", FormMethod.Post))


                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                         {
                           <input type="checkbox" name="MyID" value="@item.AllEventClasses.IsSelected"/> @item.InEventClass.ClassName <br />
                           <input type="hidden" name="CompeditorID" value="@item.InEventClass.CompeditorId" />
                           }
                        }

                    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View accepts a model of IEnumerable eManager.Web2.Models.CompDetailPlus which would be fine, but your controller is sending a single eManager.Web2.Models.CompDetailPlus object.

Try changing this in your View

```
    @model IEnumerable<eManager.Web2.Models.CompDetailPlus>
```

to this:

```
    @model eManager.Web2.Models.CompDetailPlus
```

And change the bottom part of your view so that it's iterating through Enumerable compaosite items inside your model.

Comment: Maybe a beginner error, but in the object, it contains all parts of the model.. A competitor, and the two sets of data in the IEnumerable elements.  How would I set the object (Model) to be IEnumerable?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean in the comment, but on examining your code in more detail, it looks like your View should be changed, rather than your viewmodel or controller. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks Chad.. I have tried this already and the view still has no idea of how to see the Model from the controller.  Its like the View can see the controller, but has no way of seeing the specifics in the deeper models that feed the ViewModel.

Comment: Wait.. I need to retract my comment.  This did work for the Compeditor side.!!  Let me see if I can get the lists in now.. THANK YOU so far!!

Comment: That could be because, after this change, part of the view is right (the top part) but the foreach would have to change to var item in Model.AllEventClasses. If that still doesn't work (or you've already applied the same fix), I'll try to run code based off of  your on my machine. I would have done that earlier but it's a bit of an effort. In any event, the model excepted by the view has to match whats sent by the controller.

Comment: var item in Model.AllEventClasses !

Comment: Let me try this first.. before you construct anything.. I think you are right on target.  Compeditor is now resolving.

Comment: Yes!! I have success!!  Getting both to the view now.  From here I can clean the rest up.  A simple beginner mistake that I have been looking at for 6 hours.. ha.  Thanks again for your help!!